# VB.NET Dealing with part of equation producing an overflow exception

Tags: vb.net, types, integer-overflow

As a simple example, the following code produces an overflow exception:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim x As Int16 = 2 ^ 10
    Dim y As Int16 = 2 ^ 10
    Dim z As Int16

    z = CType(x * y / y, Int16)

    Console.WriteLine(z)
    Console.Read()

End Sub
```

When performing arithmetic, it appears that since the equation is calculated progressively, part of the equation will produce a result larger than the datatype that the result will be going into. I know I could just make z a larger datatype such as Int32, but is there a way to say evaluate the expression as an Int32 then try to convert it to an Int16 before it is stored in z?

Comment: That code also wont compile under Option Strict

Answer (score 0):

You can convert x and y (Int16) to x2 and y2 (Int32) and calculate using x2 and y2.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim x As Int16 = 2 ^ 10
    Dim y As Int16 = 2 ^ 10
    Dim z As Int16

    Dim x2 As Int32 = x
    Dim y2 As Int32 = y
    z = CType(x2 * y2 / y2, Int16)

    Console.WriteLine(z)
    Console.Read()
End Sub
```